# Matplotlib: Can't re-draw first axis after clearing second using twinx() and cla()

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm having a strange issue with a second axis... not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

From the [twinx example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html) twin axis code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()


t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)
s1 = np.exp(t)
ax1.plot(t, s1, 'b-')
ax1.set_xlabel('time (s)')
# Make the y-axis label and tick labels match the line color.
ax1.set_ylabel('exp', color='b')
for tl in ax1.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('b')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
s2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
ax2.plot(t, s2, 'r.')
ax2.set_ylabel('sin', color='r')
for tl in ax2.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('r')

plt.show()
```

I get the following figure.

[image: sample]

If I clear the first axis before drawing by adding in `ax1.cla()` before `plt.show()` it clears the first axis, as expected.

[image: clear first axis]

If I clear the second axis before drawing by adding in `ax2.cla()` before `plt.show()` it clears both axis. Not quite as expected, but appears to be [a known issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3633). (edit: maybe it doesn't exactly clear both axis, the axis labels are still blue for the first axis...)

[image]

For my purposes, that isn't a problem as I want to clear both axis anyway. But the problem I'm having comes up when I try to re-draw on the plot. If I run the following code which sets up both axis, then clears both axis, then sets them up again.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()


t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)
s1 = np.exp(t)
ax1.plot(t, s1, 'b-')
ax1.set_xlabel('time (s)')
# Make the y-axis label and tick labels match the line color.
ax1.set_ylabel('exp', color='b')
for tl in ax1.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('b')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
s2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
ax2.plot(t, s2, 'r.')
ax2.set_ylabel('sin', color='r')
for tl in ax2.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('r')

# single line addition to the two_scales.py example
# clears both ax2 and ax1 under matplotlib 1.4.0, clears only ax2 under matplotlib 1.3.1
# obviously, same result with ax2.clear() method
ax1.cla()    
ax2.cla()

# Set up the axis again

t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)
s1 = np.exp(t)
ax1.plot(t, s1, 'b-')
ax1.set_xlabel('time (s)')
# Make the y-axis label and tick labels match the line color.
ax1.set_ylabel('exp', color='b')
for tl in ax1.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('b')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
s2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
ax2.plot(t, s2, 'r.')
ax2.set_ylabel('sin', color='r')
for tl in ax2.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('r')


plt.show()
```

I see get the following figure. For some reason it won't show the first axis when I re-draw both axis.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is this behaviour expected? Are there any workarounds to be able to clear and re-draw two axis plots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're creating a *new* `ax2` by calling `twinx` again.  But the original twinned axis is still there, and due to the bug you mentioned, it's set non-transparent, so it still hides `ax1`.  In other words, the bug you mentioned causes `ax1` to be invisible because an opaque `ax2` is stacked on top of it; your code just stacks yet another axis on top of `ax2`, which still leaves `ax1` obscured by the axis "in the middle".

We can get a clue as to how to fix it from [the fix](https://github.com/tacaswell/matplotlib/commit/9ba3872780bd99eb106f7ecfa20eeaf95cf3de81) for the bug you mentioned.  Try doing `ax2.patch.set_visible(False)` at the end of your code (just before the `show`).  When I do this, both plots show up properly.